# Partial Derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y,z)=x^2+\ln(1+y)+e^{yz}$$

Why

$$f^\prime_y=\frac{1}{1+y}$$

and not

$$f^\prime_y=\frac{1}{1+y}+e^{yz}z$$

having in mind that the third addend in $f$ also contains $y$ (which is a real variable, not a constant)?

This is how I would do this:

$$f^\prime_y=0+\frac{1}{1+y}(1+y)\prime+e^{yz}(yz)\prime=\frac{1}{1+y}+e^{yz}(y\prime z+yz\prime)=\frac{1}{1+y}+e^{yz}z,\text{where }x,z=\text{constants}$$

What is it that I do not understand here?

Comment: You are correct, indeed. I don't know where this bizarre result $f^\prime_y=\frac{1}{a_2+c}$ could come from !

Comment: What you are saying is correct. I don't see where $1/(a_2+c)$ even comes from.

Comment: You are right! I agree with orion and Claude Leibovici that the result $\dfrac{1}{a_2+c}$ is wrong.

Comment: That was my mistake when trying to make something in MathJax - copied some code from other question :) Just corrected it. Please take a second look. Thanks!

Comment: You derivation is correct. However, they could take $z=0$.

Comment: What is $ \ f'_y \ $ intended to mean, if $ \ f_y \ $ is the partial derivative of $ \ f \ $ with respect to $ \ y \ $ ?

Comment: @RecklessReckoner - yes, that's exactly what it means. The first answer (that I compare my answer to) is in a book that I am studying from.

Comment: I'm asking because usually $ \ f_y \ $ _already_ denotes $ \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \ . $  I'm wondering whether something else is being indicated by the use of the "prime" mark.  Otherwise, I'd simply agree that there is something wrong.

Comment: Ok, so you guys all agree that $f^\prime_y$ (or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ if you wish) is $\frac{1}{1+y}+e^{yz}z$ and not $\frac{1}{1+y}$ ?